# Can someone tell me why this lambda sort expression doesn't work?

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm new to lambda expressions, and just ran into something I don't understand.

I have an object like so:

```
class MyListItem
{
   string date; //date in the format "2010-12-05"
   int Hour;    //hour of day as an int

}
```

I have a list of these objects, representing some dates and hours.

I want to sort this list by date and hour, so I try this:

```
List<MyListItem> myList = new List<MyListItem>();

myList = getsomedata(); //populate list

myList.Sort((a, b) => (a.date + a.Hour.ToString()).CompareTo(b.date + b.Hour.ToString()));
```

and that works, sort of. The issues is that the hour is an int, so it's sometimes not 2 digits, resulting in a sort like so:

```
2010-12-05 1
2010-12-05 10
2010-12-05 11
2010-12-05 12
2010-12-05 13
2010-12-05 2
2010-12-05 21
2010-12-05 22
```

I want it to be like:

```
2010-12-05 1
2010-12-05 2
2010-12-05 10
2010-12-05 11
2010-12-05 12
2010-12-05 13
2010-12-05 21
2010-12-05 22
```

so I try formatting the string to add a zero before I parse together in the lambda:

```
ret.Sort((a, b) => (a.date + a.Hour.ToString("00")).CompareTo(b.date + b.Hour.ToString("00")));
```

But it won't compile. It tells me:

```
Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'Systems.Collections.Generic.IComparer<MyListItem>' because it is not a delegate type.
```

Huh? What is different between the plain .ToString() (with no format string) and .ToString("00") in this situation?

Also, any suggestions as to how to get this working?

Comment: What's the type of `ret`? When I make it `List<MyListItem>`, I get no compilation issues with the second sort routine. For reproducibility, what version of the compiler and framework are you using?

Comment: Strange that you get no compile errors. ret is a List<MyListItem>() (should have been myList, cut & paste error). I'm using vs2010, .net 4.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who helped. As it turns out, the issue was that in the original class, the hour was are nullable, like so:

```
class MyListItem
{
   string date; //date in the format "2010-12-05"
   int? Hour;    //hour of day as an int

}
```

The real class I'm using is a generated class that is much larger than the example I gave here - I tried to shorten it up to clarify things, and ended up leaving out the relevant part.

Changing the sort to use the value of the nullable int works:

```
myList.Sort((a, b) => (a.date + a.Hour.Value.ToString("00")).CompareTo(b.date + b.Hour.Value.ToString("00")));
```

The error message wasn't much help there, but everyone's working examples allowed me to track it down.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not at a PC so I can't explain the first, but I'd sidestep it:

```
ret.Sort((a,b) => {
    int result = string.Compare(a.date,b.date);
    if(result==0) result = a.hour.CompareTo(b.hour);
    return result;
});
```

Less string creations, no parsing overheads, etc ;)

Answer (score 2):

The reason is because it's not sorting ordinally but as a string.  You need to create a comparer to compare the dates.  Look at the sort - anything starting with a 1 precedes anything starting with a 2, thus you'll get: 1, 11, 111, 1111, 2, 22, 222, 222, 3, 33, 333 etc.

Try converting the resulting string to a date, that should fix it.

```
DateTime.ParseExact(a.date + hour.ToString("00"), "yyyy-MM-dd HH", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Should sidestep the compilation issue regarding the exception caused by the ToString().

Comment: What does this have to with the compilation issue?

Comment: @Ani: I think this answer suggests a better technique to solve the OP problem.

Comment: The date is sortable "as is" - "yyyy mm dd" is fine to sort without having to parse; and the OP is *already* trying to take steps to address the hour in a way *that is validly sortable as a string*...

Comment: Nothing to do with the compilation issue, but everything to do with the sort issue.

Comment: Yes, but the OP already notes that in the question - it is his attempt to fix it that isn't working (or even compiling)

Comment: DateTime.ParseExact("2011-01-05 01", "yyyy-MM-dd HH", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) works just fine as well... I'm not criticizing his approach, I'm saying (just as you are) that this would sidestep

Answer (score 2):

I can see your code above working perfectly fine with and without formatting. I see no reason for such wrong behaviour

```
 List<MyListItem> myList = new List<MyListItem>();

        getsomedata(myList); //populate list

        myList.Sort((a, b) => (a.date + a.Hour.ToString("00")).CompareTo(b.date + b.Hour.ToString("00")));

    private void getsomedata(List<MyListItem> items)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 30; i += 3)
        {
            items.Add(new MyListItem("2010-12-05", i));
        }
        for (int i = 2; i < 30; i += 3)
        {
            items.Add(new MyListItem("2010-12-05", i));
        }
    }

    class MyListItem
    {
        public MyListItem(string date, int hour) { this.date = date; this.Hour = hour; }
        public string date; //date in the format "2010-12-05"
        public int Hour;    //hour of day as an int
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because the dates are being compared in their String form.

Change your lambda call to as follows:

```
ret.Sort((a, b) => (DateTime.Parse(a.date + " " +a.Hour.ToString("00")  
+ ":00:00").CompareTo(DateTime.Parse(b.date  + " " + b.Hour.ToString("00") + ":00:00")));
```

Comment: And "yyyy mm dd hh" etc is *fine* to sort as a string.

Answer (score 0):

You could get crazy and make an extension method that returns a DateTime, combining the existing fields - then just sort on that.

Said logic could also be used directly in the sort expression as well, but then you don't get to use an extension method :)

public static DateTime GetDate(this MyListItem myListItem)
{
   return DateTime.Parse(myListItem.date).AddHours(myListItem.Hour);
}